# CSS transition triggered by jQuery controls occurs one direction, but not the other

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I looked through several similar questions, but couldn't find anything that quite matched what I'm doing.

I'm working on a simple full-screen panel slider. Clicking the left button triggers the CSS transition perfectly, but clicking the right button just instantly skips to the next slide. For the life of me, I can't figure out why.

[Here is a codepen with a stripped down version of the problem.](http://codepen.io/jgabrielsen/pen/rxwmKr) Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $('.panel-controls .right').click(function(){
  $(event.target).closest('.block').find('.current').next().addClass('bridge');
  $(event.target).closest('.block').find('.current').removeClass('current').addClass('hidden-left');
  $(event.target).closest('.block').find('.bridge.hidden-right').addClass('current').removeClass('hidden-right bridge');
 });
 
 $('.panel-controls .left').click(function(){
  $(event.target).closest('.block').find('.current').prev().addClass('bridge');
  $(event.target).closest('.block').find('.current').removeClass('current').addClass('hidden-right');
  $(event.target).closest('.block').find('.bridge.hidden-left').addClass('current').removeClass('hidden-left bridge');
 });
});
```

```css
@mixin transition($what:all, $when:1s, $how:ease-in-out) {
 transition: $what $when $how;
}

@mixin vcenter {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.div { box-sizing: border-box; } //everything border-box by default

.block {
 position: relative;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 .panel-controls {
  z-index: 500;
  @include vcenter;
  .left, .right {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: rgba(#000, .5);
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 30px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  .left { float: left; }
  .right { float: right; }
 }
 .panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  @include transition;
 }
 .panel.current {
  left: 0vw;
  right: 0vw;
 }
 .panel.hidden-right {
  right: -100vw;
 }
 .panel.hidden-left {
  left: -100vw;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="block">
 <div class="panel-controls">
  <div class="left">&lt;</div>
  <div class="right">&gt;</div>
 </div>
 <div class="panel p1 hidden-left" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/mNlPJ8k.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="panel p2 hidden-left" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/samQF6k.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="panel p3 hidden-left" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/AbxHQUq.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="panel p4 current" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/6V4pI7q.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="panel p5 hidden-right" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/1xkwCNN.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="panel p6 hidden-right" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/tnUALvn.jpg);"></div>
 <div class="panel p7 hidden-right" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/6V4pI7q.jpg);"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: The codepen refuses to load imgur images. The snippet doesn't work for me, either

Comment: I don't see the `bridge` class in your CSS. Could you include it? Or are you just using it as a marker?

Comment: @vals Really? They're showing up for me. Whatever the case, I'll find somewhere else to host them.

Comment: @Tony L. I'm just using it as a marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these styles

```
.panel.current {
    left: 0vw; 
}
.panel.hidden-right {
    left: 100vw;
}
.panel.hidden-left {
    left: -100vw;
}
```

You were mixing left and right properties to position your elements, and then you can not transition it properly

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZrXwz)

Comment: The answer always seems so obvious once it's been pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: Happy that it helped !